# MySQL connecting to multiple Databases at same time

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple databases on my localhost using the same username and password. As information is stored in different Databases and I need to work cross databases I need to open both at the same time. I insert data into one DB and want to delete tables in the other and also data.

Here is my current connection I am trying.

```
$host = "localhost"; // Host name 
$username = "root"; // Mysql username 
$password = "@"; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "etrack"; // Database 1
$db_name2 = "gs"; // Database 2

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
$conn2 = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name2);
// Check connection
if ($conn2->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn2->connect_error);

}
```

I then run some sql strings one example is:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO unit_hx SET
                imei = '".$imei."',
                model = '".$model."',
                supp = '".$supp."',
                status = 'Scrapped',
                installer = '".$installer."',
                unit_nr = '".$unit_nr."',
                cost = '".$cost."',
                systime = '".$time."',
                msisdn = '".$msisdn."',
                sysdate = '".$date."',
                notes = '".$notes."',
                staff = '".$agent."'";
```

I want to Drop a table in database gs based on imei information retrieved in database etrack

```
DROP TABLE 'gs_object_data_'".$imei."' 
//imei information is set on the page from a previous form using $_POST
```

Would this be possible using information from DB1 to use in DB2 query and delete DB2 tables?

Edited Working Code:
To insert or update information in two different databases the following code is useful;

```
    "INSERT INTO etrack.simcard_hx SET" //etrack is the database name simcard_hx is the table name
Changing database to other database I used 
"INSERT INTO gs.simcard_hx SET" // gs being the second database
```

Comment: "Would this be possible using information from DB1 to use in DB2 query and delete DB2 tables?" -- Yes, why not. But you should look up the correct syntax for `INSERT`, you seem to confuse that with `UPDATE` and don't enclose identifiers, like table names, in single quotes. Maybe you should also read about [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), just in case.

Comment: Do you really need a separate table for the information, dropping tables like this sounds like bad database design.  Instead I would have thought that the value of `$imei` would form part of a primary key in a `gs_object_data` table.

Comment: @NigelRen yes I need to drop tables in different DB's as I have to platforms running and the one is using tables that I need to delete on information from the other platform. This is a tracking platform I already use and writing a admin platform that admins the tracking platform.

Answer (score 1):

Your `root` user should have access to both databases, so you shouldn't need the second connection. If it doesn't, create a user that does, it will simplify your life. Then, in queries you can just prefix your table names with the database name: e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM etrack.table1 t1
JOIN gs.table2 t2 ON t2.etrack_id = t1.id
```

Comment: Yes the root user is the one I am using. I have gotten the databases opened on same time I will update my code now to how to alter tables in both DB's. Your string is useful for joining but I am still battling with echo'g the imei as updated code

Comment: Can you explain in a bit more detail in your question where the imei comes from and how you want to use it to update?